# What is the meaning of ": base" in the constructor definition?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

What is the meaning of "**: base**" in the costructor of following class(MyClass) ? Please explain the concept behind constructor definition given below for class MyClass.

```
public class MyClass: WorkerThread
{
        public MyClass(object data): base(data) 
        { 
           // some code       

        }
}

public abstract class WorkerThread
{

        private object ThreadData;
        private Thread thisThread;

        public WorkerThread(object data)
        {
            this.ThreadData = data;
        }

        public WorkerThread()
        {
            ThreadData = null;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The base class is WorkerThread. When you create a MyClass, a WorkerThread *must* be created, using any of its constructors.

By writing `base(data)` you are instructing the program to use one WorkerThread's constructor which takes `data` as a parameter. If you *didn't* do this, the program would try to use a default constructor - one which can be called with no parameters.

Comment: And that baseclass constructor is guaranteed to be executed *before* the current constructor executes.

Answer (score 2):

It calls the constructor of the class it inherits from, and provides the according arguments.

Sort of like calling

```
new WorkerThread(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It means you are passing the data parameter passed to the MyClass constructor through to the constructor of the base class (WorkerThread) in effect calling

```
public WorkerThread(object data)
{
    this.ThreadData = data;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A rare case where VB may be clearer...

```
Public Class MyClass
  Inherits WorkerThread

  Public Sub New(data)
    MyBase.New(data)
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I don't like that VB makes it any clearer than you do, but the fact remains that this is.